# The value of running CHKDSK on an SSD?

Tags: windows-8, ssd, chkdsk

One of the things I commonly do on platter based HDD is run the `chkdsk /f/r` command while fixing computers. This made me think—as I am learning the do’s and don’ts of SSD drives; I recently got my first one this week—is there any benefit to that? Or does it cause any issues like excessive read/writes?

Comment: One think a person should understand is that chkdsk is a filesystem level tool.  It will detect and in some cases resolve filesystem problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chkdsk` is primarily a tool to validate the NTFS file system and fix inconsistencies if found.  It's not really an optimizing tool like a defragmenting program.

If you have file system corruption, you need to run it, irrespective of the medium.

Regarding the `/r` flag, here's what it does according to [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/187941):

> The fourth stage of CHKDSK is only invoked if the /R switch is used.
>
> /R is used to locate bad sectors in the volume's free space. When /R
>   is used, CHKDSK attempts to read every sector on the volume to confirm
>   that the sector is usable.
>
> Sectors associated with metadata are read
>   during the natural course of running CHKDSK even when /R is not used.
>   Sectors associated with user data are read during earlier phases of
>   CHKDSK provided /R is specified.
>
> When an unreadable sector is located,
>   NTFS will add the cluster containing that sector to its list of bad
>   clusters and, if the cluster was in use, allocate a new cluster to do
>   the job of the old. If a fault tolerant disk driver is being used,
>   data is recovered and written to the newly allocated cluster.
>   Otherwise, the new cluster is filled with a pattern of 0xFF bytes.
>
> When NTFS encounters unreadable sectors during the course of normal
>   operation, it will also remap them in the same way. Thus, the /R
>   switch is usually not essential, but it can be used as a convenient
>   mechanism for scanning the entire volume if a disk is suspected of
>   having bad sectors.

Reads do not wear out your SSD significantly, so there is no real harm in doing this.

The thing is, for a very long time now, hard drives have generally done their own internal re-mapping of bad sectors (this is called *sector sparing*) - and SSDs generally do the same thing.

So, these days, if the hard drive actually reports bad sectors to the OS, it has run out of internal spares, and the drive is likely in serious trouble and should not be used.  It may be more useful to monitor the drive's SMART parameters, specifically things like Reallocated Sector Count, to know what is really going on.  Sudden changes in this value indicate significant problems, but `chkdsk` would miss them as it doesn't consult SMART.

Answer (score 0):

SSDs are not as fragile as people make them out to be anymore. The technology has long been improved and they can last years with normal usage.

Just like any drive you will need to run chkdsk /f/r as needed and required to fix disk issues.

Answer (score 0):

When fixing computers it's always a good idea to run a `chkdsk /f`.

Regarding `chkdsk /r` I do not see how this could do any harm. I think it's a good possibility to check if the drive can still read all data from the flash. But if the data cannot be read anymore, I guess that trying to read the data multiple times to recover it, might not work. But even if `chkdsk /r` does not recover data, it might still be good to detect that data cannot be read anymore (assuming the SSD's controller is not just silently failing to read and remap the sector).

Answer (score 0):

First excessive reads are a non-issue.  Unless your drive is seriously messed up and needs a lot of fixing the number of writes will be trivial.

SSD have built-in error handling so until you have used up all the built-in spare sectors you should never have a bad second on an SSD.

The file system can still be damaged so running chkdsk a couple time a year can't hurt.  Things like unexpected power loss, or turning the computer off before shutdown is complete can cause the system to be off before all the buffered contents in memory are written to the disk.